# How to terminate a task based on time, regardless of trial number (Psychtoolbox)

Tags: matlab, timer, while-loop, psychtoolbox

I need to make a timer that starts counting at the beginning of a multi-phase delay task, and that ends the delay task after a certain period of time has passed, moving on to the next part of the experiment. For now, I'd like to end the task after 2 seconds have passed.

In the code below, I included an example that can be paste into an editor. I used a part of a Stroop task for this delay task that consists of one phase (in my actual code there are 3 phases, but I simplified the task for this question)-- press the 1 key for red, the 2 key for green, and the 3 key for blue. Each phase currently runs for six trials.  (just one set of 6 trials for my one phase for now).

I'd like the task itself (all phases together) to last a period of time, and then terminate at the time I set regardless of the trial number. So if the 2 seconds have passed, the task should end even if we are only on phase 1, trial number 3 of 6.

The code below that is commented out (while loop with NumSecondsStart and NumSecondsEnd) is my current attempt. I'm not sure where such a loop would go (around the phase for loop, around the trial loop?) Thanks!

CODE:

```
clear all

close all

KbName('UnifyKeyNames');

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[window, rect]=Screen('OpenWindow',0);

RED=KbName('1'); GREEN=KbName('2'); BLUE=KbName('3');

    keysOfInterest=zeros(1,256);
    keysOfInterest([RED, GREEN, BLUE])=1;
    KbQueueCreate(-1, keysOfInterest);
    KbQueueStart; 

WORDCOLORS = {'red', 'green', 'blue'};

rgbColors = [1000 0 0; 0 1000 0; 0 0 1000];

starttime=Screen('Flip',window);

KbQueueFlush;

% NumSecondsStart = GetSecs;

% while (NumSecondsEnd-NumSecondsStart) == 1

for phase = 1

    design=repmat([1 2 3], 2, 2)';

    if phase == 1

        designRand=design(randperm(length(design)),:);

        Word=WORDCOLORS(designRand(1:6));

        Color=rgbColors(designRand(:,2),:);

    end

    for trial=1:6

        if phase == 1

        DrawFormattedText(window, Word{trial},  'center'  ,'center', Color(trial,:));

         WaitSecs(rand+.5) 

        starttime=Screen('Flip',window); 

        [pressed, firstPress]=KbQueueCheck; 

        endtime=KbQueueWait();  

        RTtext=sprintf('Response Time =%1.2f secs',endtime-starttime); 

        DrawFormattedText(window,RTtext,'center'  ,'center',[255 0 255]); 

        vbl=Screen('Flip',window); 

        Screen('Flip',window,vbl+1); 

        NumSecondsEnd =GetSecs;

        end
    end
end

%                 break;

% end

ListenChar(0); 

ShowCursor(); 
Screen('CloseAll');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [`tic`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) and [`toc`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) will be your friends here...

I would also not use `while` in favour of the following:
(Assuming an iteration which has started will be allowed to finish)

Add `tic;` where you want the timing to start, **not** inside the loop or else it will reset the timer each iteration.

Add the following within the `for` loop, either at the beginning or end

```
if toc >= 2
    break
end
```

This will [`break`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/break.html) out of the `for` loop the first time it reaches this and 2 seconds or more have passed

Comment: Thanks for responding! Your loop definitely stops the program in my 1 phase case. When I add more phases though, it prevents the user from continuing to the 2nd phase but they can to get all the way through phase 1, extending the entire task for > 2 seconds.  Also, it waits for the user response (one can stare at the stimuli for several seconds, respond, and then the task will break). I need the task to stop as soon as 2 seconds is up, break out of phase 1, regardless of the trial or subject response. I’ll continue playing with tic/toc, as it seems more promising than GetSecs.

Comment: ok it seems I didn't grasp the question entirely, there is only one phase in the outer loop in the code given. I suggest taking a look at [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) instead of break.